# Express.JS user authentication - Connecting to an existing MongoDB schema of an existing database using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, authentication, mongoose-schema

I have an existing MongoDB cluster on the cloud that I've set up in MongoDB Atlas and there are a few collections that already exist in it.
I'm working on an Express.JS application that requires users to authenticate with their username and password to login to the app.
My app does not require any *signup* functionality, as all the users that can login to the app are already registered, and their data exists in the database collections (the database is a college/university database holding data of all the students, faculty, management administrators, etc., hence not requiring to sign up new users).

I've created the frontend login page that sends a post request to the Express.JS backend with the login credentials, and I just have to verify them with the user data in my collections.
In Express.JS, the way to find a matching document is to use the MongoDB Schema's `findOne()` function, but for that we need to get hold of that corresponding Schema that we're searching the data from.
This is where I'm stuck now. I know how to create a new Schema using `mongoose.model('SchemaName', Schema)`, but how do I connect to an already existing Schema in my database?

I tried specifying an empty Schema, as suggested by ChatGPT, but that isn't working and the findOne() function returns null. This is a snippet from my code (the 'role' variable is from the body of the request, that is used to specify one of the many collections, to implement role-based login):

```
const UserModel = mongoose.model(role, mongoose.Schema())

console.log(UserModel)

let user = await UserModel.findOne({ keyForUsername: username })

console.log(user)

if (!user || user.loginPwd != pwd) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" })
}
```

This code outputs (student being the role in this case):

```
Model { student }
null
```

Comment: There are quite a few gaps in your understanding. Start with [connecting](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) to MongoDB with mongoose then move onto creating a [Schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). This will naturally flow into creating [Models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) from which you use to query your data and get your users authenticated. Try not to skip any parts and then if you get stuck you will be better placed to ask a question.